# Selecting a column of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, vector

I am somewhat confused about selecting a column of an NumPy array, because the result is different from Matlab and even from NumPy matrix. Please see the following cases.

In **Matlab**, we use the following command to select a column vector out of a matrix.

```
x = [0, 1; 2 3]
out = x(:, 1)
```

Then out becomes `[0; 2]`, which is a column vector.

To do the same thing with **a NumPy Matrix**

```
x = np.matrix([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
out = x[:, 0]
```

Then the output is `np.matrix([[0], [2]])` which is expected, and it is a column vector.

However, in case of **NumPy array**

```
x = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
out = x[:, 0]
```

The output is `np.array([0, 2])` which is 1 dimensional, so it is not a column vector. My expectation is it should have been `np.array([[0], [2]])`.
I have two questions.

**1.** **Why is the output from the NumPy array case  different form the NumPy matrix case? This is causing a lot of confusion to me, but I think there might be some reason for this.**

**2.** **To get a column vector from a 2-Dim NumPy Array, then should I do additional things like expand_dims**

```
x = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
    out = np.expand_dims(x[:, 0], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Because of the way broadcasting works, you should not care if a 1-D vector is row or column. Just use it however you like.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In MATLAB everything has atleast 2 dimensions.  In older MATLABs, 2d was it, now they can have more. `np.matrix` is modeled on that old MATLAB.

What does MATLAB do when you index a 3d matrix?

`np.array` is more general.  It can have 0, 1, 2 or more dimensions.

```
x[:, 0]
x[0, :]
```

both select one column or row, and return an array with one less dimension.

```
x[:, [0]]
x[[0], :]
```

would return 2d arrays, with a singleton dimension.

In Octave (MATLAB clone) indexing produces inconsistent results, depending on which side of matrix I select:

```
octave:7> x=ones(2,3,4);
octave:8> size(x)
ans =
   2   3   4

octave:9> size(x(1,:,:))
ans =
   1   3   4

octave:10> size(x(:,:,1))
ans =    
   2   3
```

MATLAB/Octave adds dimensions at the end, and apparently readily squeezes them down on that side as well.

`numpy` orders the dimensions in the other direction, and can add dimensions at the start as needed.  But it is consistent in squeezing out singleton dimensions when indexing.

The fact that `numpy` can have any number of dimensions, while MATLAB has a minimum of 2 is a crucial difference that often trips up MATLAB users.  But one isn't any more logical than the other.  MATLAB's practice is more a more matter of history than general principals.